# Take values from multiple cells and combine them into a different single value (not simply combining the values)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need some help with Excel as I am struggling to find tips online for what I want to do.

Take my below table:

| Country | Department |
| --- | --- |
| United Kingdom | Technical |
| France | Technical |
| Germany | Call Centre |
| United States | Human Resources |

I want to add another column that looks at both columns and does the following:

1. Check what country and use a country code
2. Check what department and abbreviate it
3. Combine the new values into one, example: GB_TECH

It will need to look for values in 2 different cells and combine them into a 3rd cell with different values. It would look like this:

| Country | Department | New values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United Kingdom | Technical | GB_TECH |
| France | Technical | FR_TECH |
| Germany | Call Centre | DE_CC |
| United States | Human Resources | US_HR |

Can anyone point me in the direction of what kind of formula I would need to achieve this?

Thank you~

Comment: Do you have other tables that equate the county and department to their respective abbreviations/codes?

Answer (score 1):

Create lookup tables(if you do not already have them) that equates the values in each column with the desired output Code/Abbreviation:

[image]

Then concatenating two VLOOKUPS will create the correct output:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,F:G,2,0)&"_"&VLOOKUP(B2,I:J,2,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Scott suggested if you have tables you can do lookups against, you could use CONCAT to get what you want. The screen cap shows the formulas and the idea.

The formula so you could copy and change references.
=CONCAT(XLOOKUP(A2,A$10:A$13,B$10:B$13),"_",XLOOKUP(B2,A$17:A$19,B$17:B$19))

[image]

Hopefully, that gives you some ideas.